# How to modify only the style of the first page of the bibliography?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, bibliographystyle

I have been using my own style for the text that I am writing, this with the use of the fancyhdr package, with the following commands:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering \normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\centering \vspace*{-2.6cm}\chaptertitlename \hspace{1.9pt} {\fontsize{29}{38}\selectfont\thechapter \\
        \vspace*{-1.5cm}\hspace*{-0.15cm}{\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \char"21A9} \hspace{6.94cm} {\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \char"21AA}}}{10pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{0pt}\titlerule\vspace{1.7pt}\titlerule\vspace{-20pt}]
```

and

```
\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
\vspace{-8pt}\hrulefill
\raisebox{-2.1pt}{\quad\decofourleft \hspace*{0.7pt}\aldineleft \hspace*{-0.7pt}\decofourright\quad}\hrulefill}
```

in

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\Chaptername \hfill\hspace{6pt}\thepage}}
\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\vspace{-2.1pt}\hspace{-2pt}Ch. \thechapter}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\thepage\hfill\rightmark}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

But these commands make the first page of each chapter have the page number on the upper right side of the page putting too much space between the chapter name and the beginning of the page, I have got around that by using the `\thispagestyle{plain}` only in the first pages of each chapter/appendix,this is nice since the page number goes to the middle of the lower part of the page,  but since the bibliography is generated all at once by the `\bibliography{ref}{}` command I don't know how to modify only the first page of the bibliography, in the same spirit that I have been doing in the chapters and appendices. Can somebody help me?

Here are some images to illustrate the problem:

- Styled bulk text page header:
  [image]
- Chapter first page that is modified by `\thispagestyle{plain}`:
  [image]
- First page of the bibliography that has the problem:
  [image]

Here follows a minimal working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english,sumario=tradicional]{abntex2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}



\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering \normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\centering \vspace*{-2.6cm}\chaptertitlename \hspace{1.9pt} 
{\fontsize{29}{38}\selectfont\thechapter \\
    \vspace*{-1.5cm}\hspace*{-0.15cm} \hspace{6.94cm} }}{10pt}{\Huge} 
[\vspace{0pt}\titlerule\vspace{1.7pt}\titlerule\vspace{-20pt}]

\titleformat{\section}
{\centering \normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection}{1em}{}




% center the toc heading
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
\vspace{-8pt}\hrulefill
\raisebox{-2.1pt}{ \hspace*{0.7pt} \hspace*{-0.7pt}}\hrulefill}

\makeindex

\makepagestyle{estilo_pretextual} %%% escolha um nome
\makeevenhead{estilo_pretextual}{}{}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida \textbf \thepage}
\makeoddhead{estilo_pretextual}{}{}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida \textbf \thepage}


\renewcommand{\pretextual}{
\pagenumbering{roman} %%% ou \pagenumbering{Roman}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{estilo_pretextual}% customizing chapter pagestyle
\pagestyle{estilo_pretextual}
\aliaspagestyle{cleared}{empty}
\aliaspagestyle{part}{estilo_pretextual}
}

\let\oldtextual\textual        \oldtextual
\renewcommand{\textual}{%
\oldtextual%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
}
 \renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\hspace*{-1.5em}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 \cftsetindents{chapter}{1.5em}{0em} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


\begin{document}
 \begin{resumo}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
    Abstract in English
    
    \vspace{\onelineskip}
    \noindent
 \end{resumo}

\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\Chaptername \hfill\hspace{6pt}\thepage}}
\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\vspace{-2.1pt}\hspace{-2pt}Ch. \thechapter}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\thepage\hfill\rightmark}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\chapter{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\vspace{0.3cm}
Quantum mechanics \cite{001}.
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Introduction}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{reff}{} % Replace "reff" with the name of your bibliography file
\end{document}
```

with a reff.bib file:

```
@book{001,
title={Mathematische Grundlagen der Quantenmechanik},
author={J. von Neumann},
address = {Berlin},
year={1932},
publisher={Springer-Verlag}
}
```

Comment: Hi Felipe, without a working MWE it's hard to reproduce your error and solve it. Have you tried printing the bibliography with `\printbobliography`? There are also many options to alter the bib headings. Unfortunately, I can't test it at the moment. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: @lukeflo I have put a minimal working example, I don't think that will make any difference though, I just wanted to simply change only the style of the first page of the bibliography, in the same spirit as I do with the '\chapters', I don't think this is difficult to understand, just that the implementation of such a thing evades me.

Comment: @FelipeDilho, take a look at the abntex2 manual and the relatex `anbtex2.cls` class. Then change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

suit yourself:

```
    \documentclass{abntex2}
\usepackage{abntex2cite}




\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{plain}
Quantum mechanics \cite{001}.
\chapter{Introduction}


\chapterstyle{plain}
\bibliography{reff} % Replace "reff" with the name of your bibliography file
\thispagestyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Annnd, does not work...

Comment: @FelipeDilho, of course it does. Just copy-paste it.